# How to transfer each line of a text file to Excel cell?

Tags: python-3.x, text, string-matching

I need to transfer some pdf table content to Excel. I used the PyMuPDF module to be able to put the PDF content to a .txt file. In which it is easier to work with and I did it successfully.

[image: Here is the PDF content that I need to put in the excel cells.]

As you can see in [the .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa6sq.png) I was able to transfer each column and row of the pdf. They are displayed sequentially.

**- I need some way to read the txt strings sequentially so I can put each line of the txt into a .xlsx cell.**

**- Some way to setup triggers to start reading the document sequentially and lines to throw away.
Example: Start reading after a specific word, stop reading when some word is reached. Things like this. Because these documents have headers and unuseful information that are also transcript to the txt file. So I need to ignore some contents of the txt to gather only the useful information to put in the .xlsx cells.**

*I'm using the xlrd library, I would like to know how I can work with things here. (optional)

I don't know if it is a problem, but when I use the count method to count the number of lines, it returned only 15 lines. The document has 568 lines in total. It only showed the full empty ones.

```
    with open(nome_arquivo_nota, 'r'):
    for line in nome_arquivo_nota:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

= 15 .

Comment: 15 lines, but your text files shows more - what are the EOL of your text file, perhaps open it in e. g. a Notepad++ editor and click on "Show All Characters" - is it Cr, CrLf or only Lf? Or does a Python crack know, what lets Python think, that there is a new line?

Comment: @BitLauncher The EOL at the end of each line shows "CR LF". I dont know what it means.

Comment: Here is an introduction to CR and LF:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline